# Logo overlay my slider wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Iam working on a wordpress theme, and i want to make my logo to overlay over my slider . [image: Overlay example]

I tried couple of ways with css . But it seems that its getting bigger on smaller screens . Whould i should use media queries and make it visible none on smaller screens ?

My CSS code to the logo image.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .logo img {
        display: none !important;
    }
}

.header_mid_inner .logo img {
    max-height: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    left: 50px !important;
    top: 100px !important;
    width: 135px !important;
    height: 150px !important;
    border: 1px solid white !important;
}
```

Comment: At first better dont do that media query to display none the logo. And the second i suggest you use % on your top left. Also put the max height and the max width if you want responsivnes for your site. Would be better if you send the html code of the header to help because i think the problem stays in the positioning top and height and width

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to make the logo responsive with the banner top. To achieve this you need to use % values not pixels for height and width. Also the positioning must be in % so it will rescale with the page.